# How do we upgrade lift version in Maven?

Tags: scala, maven, upgrade, lift

I would like to upgrade lift version to bypass a lift bug. However, I cannot find the place to change the version number in Maven. Is it here?

```xml
<properties>
        <scala.version>2.7.7</scala.version>
        <!-- Common plugin settings -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <!-- vscaladoc settings -->
        <maven.scaladoc.vscaladocVersion>1.2-m1</maven.scaladoc.vscaladocVersion>
        <vscaladoc.links.liftweb.pathsufix>scaladocs/</vscaladoc.links.liftweb.pathsufix>
        <vscaladoc.links.liftweb.baseurl>http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb</vscaladoc.links.liftweb.baseurl>
</properties>
```

If so, what parameter do I adjust to do it? If not, how can I upgrade lift in Maven?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a `<dependencies>` element as a sister to `<properties>` with children like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.liftweb</groupId>
  <artifactId>lift-mapper_${scala.version}</artifactId>
  <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Just change the version as desired (noting that 2.2 is the latest version with Scala 2.7 support), or add a line like `<liftweb.version>2.2</liftweb.version>` to your properties and refer to it here:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.liftweb</groupId>
  <artifactId>lift-mapper_${scala.version}</artifactId>
  <version>${liftweb.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Note that there may be several `net.liftweb` dependencies, and that they'll all need to be changed. Using the property approach makes this process a little easier and less error-prone.

Comment: Thanks. So 'lift-mapper' is actually managing the entire version of lift, not just the mapper?

Comment: No, I just gave that as an example. Depending on your setup, `mapper` may be pulling in a lot of the other Lift artifacts as its own dependencies, though. If you've got a working project now you shouldn't need to add dependencies—you can just change the versions.

Comment: I got it. But the only lift dependency in my pom.xml is actually the mapper. I don't see anything else though. Is this a problem?

Comment: Nope, that just means it's pulling in everything you need (at least `lift-util` and `lift-webkit`, and maybe some others).

Comment: By the way, you can run `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` if you want to see exactly what's pulling in what.